# How to load L.geoJson from url?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I have a Geojson Linestring file that I would like to style.
I load it with L.mapbox.featureLayer() but I guess there is no styling option.
I try to load it with L.geoJson but does not find the way to do it through url:

```
var myStyle = {
"color": "#ff7800",
"weight": 5,
"opacity": 0.65
};
L.geoJson(myGeojson, {
style: myStyle
}).addTo(map);
```

What should I add to load the Geojson from url?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`L.geoJSON` takes an object, not a URL.  You can use jQuery's `getJSON` to load the data, then call `L.geoJSON` when it's ready:

```
$.getJSON("orders.json", function(data) {
    L.geoJson(data, {
        style: myStyle
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ for more details.

Comment: Following your answer what should I do if I want to extract a style include in the geojson itself?

Comment: `data` is your geoJSON data; look at it in the debugger and see.  The style option you have above is global; the same for every feature.  If you want each marker to be styled individually, you can use `pointToLayer` to create them.